# Kafka - AccessDeniedException when changing partition leader

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, access-denied

When running a Kafka cluster (Kafka v 2.11-1.1.0) on 2 Windows machines, it seems an AccessDeniedException is thrown when I try to change the leader for a particular topic partition. This causes the broker (current leader) to crash. This may be related to the following unresolved issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194 . Is there anything I can do about this or can you just not change the topic leader on Windows at this time without having to restart a broker?

**Steps to re-produce:**

1. Start a zookeeper service on a Windows 10 machine.
2. Start a kafka broker on the same machine.
3. Start a second kafka broker on a second Windows 10 machine connected to the same zookeeper as the first, so as to form a Kafka cluster.
4. Create a topic with 1 partition and observe the resultant leader of that partition.
5. Use kafka-reassign-partitions command (as per https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools) to change the leader for that topic partition. Use a json file similar to what is shown below where 'topicName' is replaced by the name of the topic created in step 4, and '1' is replaced by the BrokerId of the Kafka broker that is not currently the leader of this partition:

   `{
    "version":1,
    "partitions":[
         {"topic":"topicName","partition":0,"replicas":[1]}
    ]
   }`

After performing the above steps I see an the following in the log of the old topic partition leader:

```
Error while renaming dir for testTopic in log dir C:\Users\Public\Documents\Kafka\logs\ (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel) java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException
```